# How to hide stacklayout if user clicked somwhere else on screen

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I createt ResourceDictionary in App.xaml file for application header.
In header I created two dropdowns menu (with stacklayouts and grids).
First is for some user informations and second one is for search.
By default these dropdown menus are hiden.
Max one may be visible if user click on user-icon or on search-icon.
So in HeaderViewModel I cratet these two methods:

```
private async void AccountInformationAsync()
        {
            var userService = await UserService.GetUserData();
            Username = userService.Username;
            DisplayName = userService.DisplayName;
            Status = userService.Status;
            Influence = userService.Influence;
            MTP = userService.MTP;

            VisibilityInformation = !VisibilityInformation;
            if (VisibilityInformation == true)
            {
                VisibilitySearch = false;
            }
        }

        private void Search()
        {
            VisibilitySearch = !VisibilitySearch;
            if (VisibilitySearch == true)
            {
                VisibilityInformation = false;
            }
        }
```

This works fine... If user click on user-icon user info will show up and if user then click on serach-icon info will hide an search menu will show up.

So, my question is how to hide any of these menus if user click somewhere else on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an TapGestureRecognizer on the Main Layout View of the Page. And on the Tap of it you can use Command and Hide both the dropdown Menu.

```
    private void HideDropDowns()
    {
        VisibilitySearch = false;
        VisibilityInformation = false;
    }
```

HideDropDowns should be the Method assigned to the Command in the TapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: I started implementing something like that, but then I realise i have to do it on every single page on application and on every layout even on some certain element I should add tapgesture for hiding theese two elements.
Is there any simple solution?

Comment: You can make a CustomContentPage and add a TapGestureRecognizer to the parent element and then make all other pages implement this CustomContentPage.